# Wrong redirection after Login in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

may I ask why I am getting redirected to this weird url location after login? ( I have made sure my HOME in RouteServiceProvider is correct and I am using jetstream )

[image]

Comment: Status Code 302 means there is at least function return false and it goes wrong. It should be Status Code 200. Please share more information about the problem.

Comment: I think by default the Route::redirect returns a 302 status code.

Comment: Facing same problem.